# Is it possible to build an Apple Watch App with flutter?

Tags: flutter, apple-watch, watchos, bitcode

How is it possible to make an Apple Watch App with flutter?

I know that bitcode support is crucial for this. But I thought it was added in Flutter 1.9 . I just couldn't find any tutorials or any other resources to get started, since the github thread for this is closed and doesn't provide any helpful information on how to get started or compile with bitcode enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It is possible to use flutter to create something to Watch OS or Android Wear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189479/it-is-possible-to-use-flutter-to-create-something-to-watch-os-or-android-wear)